# Spring Boot + Gradle : how to build rpm

Tags: gradle, rpm

```
How to Build sping boot Jar with RPM with Gradle.
```

jar is working fine.while packing rpm not running by default

jar ==> output =ok

jar ==> RPM ==output not working.not running jar inside.

Any one please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend this gradle plugin to build RPM
https://github.com/nebula-plugins/gradle-ospackage-plugin